# Real Time user Tracking with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-directions-api

I want to create the same functionality as Google Maps application in a website using the JavaScript API of Google Maps. I can get the current user location and updating it through `setinterval` on the map.

Issue is: I am getting multiple direction suggestions with the direction API. So If I select the second route from suggested routes from Google, it shows the second route direction but on page refresh it shows the first direction.

Also, I want to track the users by the admin with their user ID. I can locate them but I am not able to show the direction on the map for admin.

Anyone have idea regarding this?

Basically I am creating a site which can enable users to track their travel and help them reach their destination, track their location and save it in the database.

Here is the development site:

https://www.aghadiinfotechforclient2.com/track/
user: demo pass:demo@123

And locating the user link is: 
https://www.aghadiinfotechforclient2.com/track/locate with user ID: 5

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use watchPosition and not setInterval. Secondly I'd ignore direction and use google maps instructions for journey.

Comment: Thanks you for this help. So with watchPosition(), I will set the pointer on maps. But need to set the directions and watch out on direction by admin is a big issue. Also I can not get the selected direction from the google maps direction api so I can set that direction again with page refresh and set to admin as well.

Comment: Please explain what direction is being used for. You can plot the path with Google Maps. Or you can simply use the lng/lt deltas to plot degrees of direction.

Comment: Suppose we are going from place 1 to place 2, and there are three ways to go over there (way1, way2, way3). Google map's direction api is used for this and that are showing the direction for the users. But that direction is only limited to driver. In the map, suggested routes are displayed and among those routes, user can select their routes and go with that. But i would need to set that direction for other map which is being displayed on admin's screen. I can set the lat/lng of users but not able to track the direction which is being displayed at user's screen.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the map orientation?

Comment: Yes, So we can track where our employees are and where they are going through website because they have to keep active our site in their browser. And we can keep watch on them